# Heroku - /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a rails app and when I run it locally, it works fine. But when I upload my app to Heroku, I get the following error when uploading:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
```

and this error when I request the page:

```
2014-02-03T01:52:52.032866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"       method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=whispering-fortress-2710.herokuapp.com request_id=5db8fbf4-2250-4e95-8b99-387f98248f02 fwd="50.148.151.110" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try pushing your app once again in a new heroku app

Comment: have you specified the ruby version explicitly in **Gemfile** or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I found that, in addition to specifying your ruby version in the Gemfile (use ruby -v, will probably return 1.9.3, so add `ruby '1.9.3'` to the Gemfile), I needed to change the first line of the_app/bin/rake, the_app/bin/rails, the_app/bin/bundle.

The line might say

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
```

Change it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Let me know if that works!

Answer (score 2):

This is because your ruby version is outdated. Just update your ruby and it works fine. Do `sudo apt-get install ruby` , this will update your ruby if not installed othervise install it to latest version. Hope this works! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

specify ruby version to use, added below entry for Cedar stack on heroku
In Gemfile
add following line

ruby "1.9.3" # or whatever version you wish to use on heroku stack